# Parallel.Foreach: All threads completed but not all performed all underlying functions

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I apologize in advance if question seems vague or repeated.

I am trying to execute a set of functions on a list of objects using Parallel.ForEach

```
Parallel.Foreach(listOfObjects,obj=>
{
    ProcessEachObject(obj);
});
```

ProcessEachObject function calls couple of functions to process the object. This includes functions to interact with DB(DB2 through ADO.NET) as well

```
ProcessEachObject(ClassSample obj)
{
    subProcess1();
    insertIntoDB();
    subProcess2();
    subProcess3();
    updateDB();       //row inserted above is updated
}
```

When I use foreach loop I see the updates done in all rows. However , when i use Parallel.Foreach nearly half the rows are not updated. Am I missing synchronzation at some place? Are the queries not synchronized on threads internally? Please help

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, this is impossible to answer. Simplify your code as much as you can and then post a complete sample here.

Comment: Also, you should try debugging your code yourself, to see what's actually going on and if the functions are not actually executed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @svick . I will try to produce more code. But could you please tell me if multiple threads through parallel.foreach requres synchronization on SQL queries or it is handled internally in someway?

Comment: @nishantv Are the threads affecting the same rows of the SQL table ? If yes, it needs synchronization, if no, it's ok.

Comment: @svick no each object(and thus each threadI inserts its own row and updates this row at the end of processing

Comment: @C4stor You're wrong. The database can handle multiple concurrent accesses, even to the same data.

Comment: @nishantv That depends on how are you using the database. For example, if you're using the same connection or context object from multiple threads, that most likely won't work properly.

Comment: @svick Yeah, but depending on the operation made, it may or may not be safe. I should have wrote "may need synchronization" indeed.